# Using the veclen option in the calc package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a circle about point `P = (-2.75,0.75)` so that a vertex `A = (0,0)` of a rectangle is on the circumference, and I would like to draw a circle about `P` of a radius equal to twice the distance between `P` and `A`.  I tried using the code

```
 \draw[green, dashed, name path=another_path_to_locate_R] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle (2*{veclen(\x1,\y1)});
```

and

```
 \draw[green, dashed, name path=another_path_to_locate_R] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle ($2*{veclen(\x1,\y1)}$); .
```

I got errors

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\coordinate (A) at (0,0);


\coordinate (P) at (-2.25,0.75);

\draw[name path=another_circle_about_P] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
 %\draw[green, dashed, name path=another_path_to_locate_R] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle ($2*{veclen(\x1,\y1)}$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the dollar signs, and move `*` to right before `veclen`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-2.25,0.75);
\draw[name path=another_circle_about_P] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\draw[green, dashed, name path=another_path_to_locate_R] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in (P) circle ({2*veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## A different way

One quite easy way of drawing a circle around one point, passing through another, is with the help of the `through` library. It defines one key, `circle through`, and does exactly that job.

The second circle is drawn using `let`, from the `calc` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-2.25,0.75);
\fill (A) circle[radius=2pt] (P) circle[radius=2pt];
\node [draw,circle through={(A)}] at (P) {};
\draw
let
 \p1=(A), \p2=(P), \n1={2*veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\y1)}
in
(P) circle[radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know why the command that I issued to draw the circle about `P` of radius twice the distance between `P` and `A=(0,0)` could not be compiled?

Comment: @user74973 I just updated my answer.

Comment: Yep.  I posted my comment as you were updating your answer.  And your update anticipated my question.  Thanks.